ValueError: Number of classes does not match size of target_names for a confusion matrix
I have this code which produces a Value error.
y = df['weather type'] 
# y is an array with the 11 unique values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
# and of an 'object' type:
array([10, 10, 10, ..., 10, 10,  9])

# Encode the target variable (weather type) to numeric values - 
# not sure if I should have done this step because it seems to have messed up my target labels?
y_le = LabelEncoder()
y = y_le.fit_transform(y)

# the unique values of y_le.classes_ are '0', '1', '10', '11', '12', '2', '3', '5', '6', '7', '8'
# the unique values of y_val are 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

# Initialize the XGBoost classifier
xgb_model = xgb.XGBClassifier(objective='multi:softmax', num_class=len(le.classes_))

# Train the model
xgb_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Make predictions on the validation set 
y_pred_val = grid_search.predict(X_val)

# Evaluate the model
# Print classification report and confusion matrix
print("\nClassification Report:\n", classification_report(y_val, y_pred_val, target_names=y_le.classes_))

The value error is as follows:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[292], line 6
      2 y_pred_val = xgb_model.predict(X_val)
      4 # Evaluate the model
      5 # Print classification report and confusion matrix
----> 6 print("\nClassification Report:\n", classification_report(y_val, y_pred_val, target_names=y_le.classes_))
      7 #print("\nClassification Report:\n", classification_report(y_val, y_pred_val, labels=range(len(y_le.classes_)), target_names=y_le.classes_))

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py:2332, in classification_report(y_true, y_pred, labels, target_names, sample_weight, digits, output_dict, zero_division)
   2326         warnings.warn(
   2327             "labels size, {0}, does not match size of target_names, {1}".format(
   2328                 len(labels), len(target_names)
   2329             )
   2330         )
   2331     else:
-> 2332         raise ValueError(
   2333             "Number of classes, {0}, does not match size of "
   2334             "target_names, {1}. Try specifying the labels "
   2335             "parameter".format(len(labels), len(target_names))
   2336         )
   2337 if target_names is None:
   2338     target_names = ["%s" % l for l in labels]

ValueError: Number of classes, 10, does not match size of target_names, 11. Try specifying the labels parameter

as far as I can see, I have already set target_names=y_le.classes_.
How to fix this?
Additionally my target variable, weather_type is an 'object' data type, and I am not sure if I should converted it to numeric for an XGBoost multi-classification model?

y_val is not assigned in the code snippet. What is y_val?
Check for the data type of df['weather type']
df['weather type'].dtypes

For classification problems sklearn expects int as target. If your data type is int, then there is no need to use LabelEncoder(). LabelEncoder() takes an object type and maps to an int.

'cat' -> 0; 'dog' -> 1

If your y is of type object but all the values appear to be int it could be because of null values.
df['weather type'].isnull().sum()

If you have nulls drop it and try
